# Protractor via eclipse (kepler) it throws an error

Tags: eclipse, protractor

Question - Running the config.js from command prompt the code runs fine but when running via eclipse (kepler) it throws an error.

Protractor Version -- 5.1.2
NPM Version -- 3.10.8

Command  line: protractor config.js woks fine.

### In eclipse:

Running the runner.bat file via external configuration

```
Location: ${workspace_loc:/Com.AngularMobileApp/Runner.bat}
Directory: ${workspace_loc:/Com.AngularMobileApp}
```

Error on execution -- 'protractor' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Please assist.

Comment: Install protractor globally.

Comment: D:\>npm install -g protractor
C:\Users\jacob.samuel\AppData\Roaming\npm\protractor -> C:\Users\jacob.samuel\Ap
pData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor
C:\Users\jacob.samuel\AppData\Roaming\npm\webdriver-manager -> C:\Users\jacob.sa
muel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\bin\webdriver-manager
C:\Users\jacob.samuel\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- protractor@5.1.2                                                                                                         I have installed it on global level only but I still get the same issue :-(